# Odoo: Unable to install module "base_report_to_printer" because an external dependency is not met: No module named cups

Tags: odoo

I am trying to install "base_report_to_printer" module on odoo 12.0, i followed the steps in this page
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/base_report_to_printer/

yet i still get the error below when i try installing the module

Odoo: Unable to install module "base_report_to_printer" because an external dependency is not met: No module named cups

I am using odoo 12.0 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: did you read the ìndex page of the app `Installation section it shows you how to install the dependency using PIP`

Comment: Yes i did exactly as it said
sudo apt-get install cups
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo pip install pycups

Comment: Then just restart your server and create new db

Comment: i did restart my server several times, but creating a new db isn't possible since all the data is in the old one

Comment: check if you installed the package using the right pip command, may be you have to version of python and you need to use PIP3 instead of PIP

Comment: i installed it using both versions of pip

Comment: do you use a container software like docker for odoo?

Comment: no, not even familiar with them, i use it on a laptop with ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, by following this post 
https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/11-0-how-to-install-pycups-module-on-odoo-sh-148293

You should put cups module in your requirements.txt file
Put the below line, it should work

cups==0.0.6